# Accelerometer data: How to interpret? Sparkfun ADXL335 with Arduino

Tags: arduino, accelerometer

X:471 Y:486 Z:476 
X:468 Y:478 Z:467 
X:454 Y:460 Z:450 
X:436 Y:435 Z:422 
X:392 Y:379 Z:364 
X:327 Y:305 Z:296 
X:270 Y:248 Z:250 
X:248 Y:236 Z:246 
X:260 Y:258 Z:269 
X:292 Y:297 Z:307 
X:321 Y:331 Z:341 
X:375 Y:398 Z:406 
X:439 Y:465 Z:465 
X:478 Y:502 Z:494 
X:489 Y:503 Z:491 
X:478 Y:487 Z:475
X:462 Y:465 Z:451
X:413 Y:401 Z:385 
X:343 Y:321 Z:313 
X:272 Y:247 Z:249 
X:253 Y:239 Z:248 
X:260 Y:256 Z:268 
X:288 Y:293 Z:304 
X:320 Y:330 Z:340 
X:374 Y:394 Z:400 
X:436 Y:464 Z:463
Here is my sample of data (Not moving at all) I don't know what can i do with all these data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a blog post about this device on an Arduino that should answer your questions.

http://chrisheydrick.com/2015/02/05/adxl335-accelerometer-on-an-arduino/

In short, the values you're seeing depend on the power delivered to the ADXl335.

The sensitivity (mV/g) is stated to be ratiometric in the data sheet, and the example given is that when you deliver 3V to the power supply, the sensitivity is 300 mV/g. In a later section called “Use with operating voltages other than 3V” it gives the example of 360 mV/g with a 3.6V power supply, and 195 mV/g with a 2V power supply. You can pretty much gather that the sensitivity in mV/g is the power supply voltage divided by 10. More or less.

Another ratiometric value is the “0g bias”. The accelerometer chip can detect negative acceleration, but it doesn’t output a negative voltage signal. What you do is consider the middle point of the power supply voltage range the 0 point. My power supply voltage is 3.3V, so I have to treat 1.6V as the zero point. You’ll add have to subtract that zero point from any voltage reading to get the actual mV/g value.